# Problems with jQuery templates. Object doesn't support this method error

Tags: jquery, templates

I am learning about template in jquery. And have get over some example code that I testing. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript" />
</head>

<body>

    <h2>ViewPage1</h2>

    <script id="movieTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
        <li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>
    </script>

    <div id="movieList"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var movies = [
                { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
                { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
                { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
                ];

            // Render the template with the movies data and insert
            // the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element
            $("#movieTemplate").tmpl(movies).appendTo("#movieList");
    </script>
</body>
```

When debugging I can see that the problem is with the .appendTo() method. And I can also see in intellisens that that method is not in there.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What does $("#movieTemplate").tmpl(movies) return? The "tmpl" function may not be chain-able, so you're attempting to access a jQuery method on a non-jQuery object.

A good way to debug is to break up chained calls into individual statements. That makes it easier to set breakpoints and see the return value of each function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the script definitions in the header:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript" />
</head>
```

The script tag needs to have a closing `</script>` tag.  Essentially your tmpl script wasn't loading.  I did notice this is a bug in the tmpl example, so not really your fault.  If you change the second one to match the first, it works fine:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/UZ62w/

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the tmpl not returning a jQuery object. Try modifying your js to resemble something like this

```
var movies = [
            { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
            { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
            { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
            ],
template = $("#movieTemplate").tmpl(movies);

$("#movieList").append(template);
```

**edit:** Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lmcculley/fe5kU/) showing it works.

Comment: The reason yours works and his doesn't has nothing to do with the modification here.  It works because you changed how the library was loaded.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and setting the record straight, sir. It is much appreciated. :-)