# How to retrieve multiple records from Jquery to my RazorView page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I have a button "btnGetAddress" on my razor page .On clik of this button,I am calling a Jquery to get my addressItmes object to be displayed on to my View page.

On clicking "btnGetAddress"  I am able to hit my `"JsonResult GetAddresses()"` and retrieve records within my Jquery `(success: function (data))`.and this data has multiple address records. But I do not know how to take this data to my view .Please help me to get my data to be displayed on to my View

When my page get loaded,the user will see only the "btnGetAddress" button .When the user click on the btnGetAddress, it will call the Jquery Click function to fetch all address records from database and display each set of records on the page

```
$("#btnGetAddress").click(function () { 

                debugger;
                var selected = $("#ddlType").val();
                if (selected == "")
                { selected = 0; }
                var dataToSend = {
                    SelectedTypeId: selected
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAddresses", "Content")',
                    data: { SelectedTypeId: selected },
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;

                    },

                    error: function (error) {
                        var verr = error;
                        alert(verr);
                    }

                });
```

pasted below is my  JsonResult GetAddresses() which gets called to retrieve addressItems

```
public JsonResult GetAddresses()
        {
   model.AddressItems = AddressService.RetrieveAllAddress(); 
 // My AddressItems is of type IEnumerable<AddressItems>   


 return Json(model.AddressItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my razor View Page where the address records are to be displayed.

```
 ........................

  <input type="submit" id="btnGetAddress" name="btnSubmit" value="Show Addresses" />

  if (!UtilityHelper.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.AddressItems))
    {

        foreach (var AddressRecord in Model.AddressItems)
        {
    <fieldset >
        <legend style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: small;">Address Queue(@Model.NumRecords)
        </legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Index</span>

                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnDelete" name="btnSubmit" value="X" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Address1</span>
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => AddressRecord.Address )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => AddressRecord.Address)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Description</span>
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => AddressRecord.Description)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => AddressRecord.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnDelete" name="btnSubmit" value="Delete" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
        }
        }

    <fieldset>
```

Or is there any better way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the data via ajax you should use a jquery template engine. Basically get the data the way you are and on success you do something like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/getprojects", "", function (data) {
            $("#projectsTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#projectsList");
        });
    });
</script>

<script id="projectsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <section>
        <header><h2>Projects</h2></header>
        <table id="projects">
            <th>Name</th>
            {{tmpl(items) "#projectRowTemplate"}}
        </table>
    </section>
</script>

<script id="projectRowTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/show/${id}">${name}</a></td>
  </tr>
</script>

<div id="projectsList"></div>
```

Now each template engine is different but the above gives you an idea of what you can do

Comment: I am getting an exception "Object doesn't support property or method 'tmpl'"  inside Jquery1.5.1.js

Comment: Did you download and include jquery.tmpl from https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Comment: I downloaded and included all  libraries ,but I am still getting the same errror  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tmpl'"

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740813/problems-with-jquery-templates-object-doesnt-support-this-method-error ?

Comment: As you suggested I included "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"  and it worked perfectly .   Thank you @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return JSON object in your controller, you are going have to turn your view into a string and return it as part of the message. If you google there are some methods out there that can do this.

However, I really think that's the hard way, why not take the data you get from the JSON in the  controller and put it in a MODEL and then return your VIEW with the model data passed in. I think that's the easier way.